# How to make only the outside components in a row have bigger margins

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I have a row of reactstrap cards and I want the one on the left to have margin-left of 2rem and the one on the right to have a margin-right of 2rem. All the other side margins should be 1rem.

However these cards are implemented as a separate component so I can't hard code the margins since they're all being used by a parent component. Is there any prop I can pass in that says to change the margin based on position?

What's also complicated is that the number of cards in a row changes based on screensize, so I can't just say "if it's a multiple of x, then have this style".

Here's the component:

```
<Card
    outline
    as='a'
    style={{ cursor: 'pointer', margin: '1rem' }}
  >
    <CardImg top width='100%' src={img}' />
    <CardBody>
      <CardTitle tag='h5'>{this.props.title}</CardTitle>
    </CardBody>
  </Card>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the parent, use the CSS selectors for first child and last child.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-child

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-child

Comment: Would this work for each row if there are multiple rows?

Comment: If each row is in an element, such a div or the likes then yes. Otherwise, use nth-child().

Comment: hmmm well for small screens there's 2 in a row, for large there's 3, so any advice on what to do in that case?

Comment: Look into the HTML structure - is it done using flexbox perhaps? otherwise, you can use a media-query.

I think the very best way to do it is to use padding in the container, to move the content in from the sides.